# How to grab the last result of a find command?

Tags: bash

The result of my find command produces the following result

```
./alex20_0  
./alex20_1  
./alex20_2  
./alex20_3
```

I saved this result as a variable. now the only part I really need is whatever the last part is or essentially the highest number or "latest version".

So from the above string all I need to extract is `./alex20_3` and save that as a variable. Is there a way to just extract whatever the last directory is outputted from the find command?

I would do the last nth characters command to extract it since its already in order, but it wouldn't be the same number of characters once we get to version `./alex20_10` etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
your_find_command | tail -n 1
```

Comment: my find command is this (find . -maxdepth 1 -name "*string*" -print)

where would I insert the | tail -n 1???

Comment: At the very end. By the way, this will *not* necessarily extract the latest version but only the last file listed by `find`. The order in which `find` lists files is rather random.

Answer (score 2):

`find` can list your files in any order. To extract the latest version you have to sort the output of `find`. The safest way to do this is

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name "string" -print0 | sort -zV | tail -zn1
```

If your implementation of `sort` or `tail` does not support `-z` and you are sure that the filenames are free of line-breaks you can also use

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name "string" -print | sort -V | tail -n1
```

Answer (score 0):

There could be multiple ways to achieve this -

**Using the 'tail' command** (as suggested by @Roadowl)

find branches -name alex* | tail -n1

**Using the 'awk' command**

find branches -name alex* | awk 'END{print}'

**Using the 'sed' command**

find branches -name alex* | sed -e '$!d'

Other possible options are to use a bash script, perl or any other language. You best bet would be the one that you find is more convenient.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want the file name sorted by the highest version, you can try as follows

```
$ ls
alex20_0    alex20_1    alex20_2    alex20_3
$ find .  -iname "*alex*" -print | sort  | tail -n 1
./alex20_3
```